# How to change passed variable inside event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, event-handling, jquery-events

I would like to know if there is a way to change "external" variable with handling the event

```
function generateHTML()
{
    var html = '';

    // Some html generating code
    html += '<b>John Doe</b>';

    $(document).trigger('html:generating', html);

    // Do more hardcoded stuff with html

    $(document).trigger('html:generated', html);

    return html;
}

$(document).on('html:generating', function(e, html) {
    html = '<span>' + html + '</span>';
});

$(document).on('html:generated', function(e, html) {
    console.log(html);  // prints <b>John Doe</b>
                        // expected <span><b>John Doe</b></span>
});

generateHTML();
```

This would be very useful when handling Mustache (or any other template library) dynamic html code.

Comment: try `.load`?  `.on` already working on dynamic element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about passing html by reference, there is a way to do it. Everything you pass as a function argument is passed by value, but if you pass an object, the object properties still point to the original values, as the pointers are copied. So, you could do something like this:

```
function generateHTML()
{
    var container={html: ''};

    // Some html generating code
    container.html += '<b>John Doe</b>';

    $(document).trigger('html:generating', container);

    // Do more hardcoded stuff with html

    $(document).trigger('html:generated', container);

    return container.html;
}

$(document).on('html:generating', function(e, container) {
    container.html = '<span>' + container.html + '</span>';
});

$(document).on('html:generated', function(e, container) {
    console.log(container.html);
});

generateHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you, I could solve it on my own (I knew the fact that objects are passed by reference), but was too tired to find so simple yet perfect solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the variable into a higher scope (as @potter suggested). It may be easier to work with if you create an object although if you are performing very simple tasks may not be necessary.

Ideally the 'Renderer' code would be in its own file to be reused.

See code variation below for a basic example.

```js
// Some Object
var Renderer = function(scope, args) {
 var self = this;
  var scope = $(scope) || $(document);
  var html = args.html || "";
  
  self.setHtml = function(setHtml){
   html = setHtml;
  }
  
  self.getHtml = function(){
   return html || "";
  }
  
  self.generateHTML = function() {
    scope.trigger('html:generating', self.getHtml());

    // Do more hardcoded stuff with html
  
    scope.trigger('html:generated', self.getHtml());
  }
  return self;
}


// Your Code
var contentScope = document;
var contentRenderer = new Renderer(contentScope, {html: "<b>John Doe</b>"});

$(contentScope).on('html:generating', function(e, html) {
    contentRenderer.setHtml('<span>' + html + '</span>');
});

$(contentScope).on('html:generated', function(e, html) {
    console.log(html);  // prints <b>John Doe</b>
                        // expected <span><b>John Doe</b></span>
});

contentRenderer.generateHTML();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution itself is not bad as long as it works, but I think it's overcomplicated. Kamyar posted simplest answer with nothing more but reusing the way JS works.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into how closures work. (all javascript functions are closures)

For this specific question, all you have to do is move the declaration of your html variable outside of your functions, into a higher scope. Then if you still want to pass the variable in the event handlers you need to use a different name.

```
var outerHtml = '';
function generateHTML() {    
    // Some html generating code
    outerHtml += '<b>John Doe</b>';

    $(document).trigger('html:generating', html);

    // Do more hardcoded stuff with html

    $(document).trigger('html:generated', html);

    return outerHtml;
}

$(document).on('html:generating', function(e, html) {
    outerHtml = '<span>' + html + '</span>';
});

$(document).on('html:generated', function(e, html) {
    console.log(outerHtml);  // prints <b>John Doe</b>
                        // expected <span><b>John Doe</b></span>
});

generateHTML();
```

Comment: You don't need global variable if you can pass the object instead of primitive-type variable (so called pass-by-reference).

Comment: my assumption is that most people know how to set up a properly modulized file. If not, explaining it is too much for a super basic scoping question.

Comment: Actually the JS itself is not "modulized" (I guess you mean "structured") in any way, as this is the only one OO language without OO traits like interfaces of classes, so the structure of the files and overall code depends only on company standards / personal programmer knowledge & taste. Using global variables as a solution is rarely preffered in any programming language (it does not mean it can't work, it is just getting messy when project grows).

Comment: I did not mean structured, and I was not suggesting use of global variables. Moving variable declaration to a higher scope is standard practice in languages that support first class functions. If you want to isolate code in es5, all you have to do is wrap the file in an IIFE. if you're using import syntax with a build process then files are very much modularized.